# Convert array returned from function to columns

Tags: arrays, function, postgresql

I have a function in PostgreSQL (PLPGSQL) that returns an array containing two elements.  When I run a select statement calling the function, I get a column containing the array (as expected):

```
{1, 2}
```

What I really would like to do is extract these elements to be their own columns:

```
[ 1 | 2 ]
```

I have found that I can do:

```
SELECT (MyFunction())[1], (MyFunction())[2]
```

But that calls the function twice, therefore doubling the run time (this function is a very time-consuming function).  Is there a better way to handle this?

Here is an almost perfect replica of what I have:

```
SELECT table1.a, table1.b, table1.c, (MyFunction(table1.a, table1.b, table1.c))[1],
(MyFunction(table1.a, table1.b, table1.c))[2]
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 using(b)
WHERE ... GROUP BY table1.a, table1.b, table1.c;
```

Again, this produces the two columns from the array, but my function is called twice, which doubles my run time.

Comment: I will note that the number of elements in the returning array will ALWAYS be 2...

Comment: If the shape of the returned result is known, should you be returning an array at all? that should probably be a row.  Do you have the ability to refactor that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

can you use a subselect?

```
postgres=# select ar[1], ar[2] from (select string_to_array('a b c', ' ') ar) as sq;
 ar | ar 
----+----
 a  | b
(1 row)
```

This still requires you explicitly extract each column (like you already do).  If there are more elements in the array than extracted, they will be lost, and if there are fewer, then the missing columns will just be `NULL`.

EDIT: I think I would wrap the whole thing in a subselect;  the inner subselect generates the desired *rows*, with the outer select projecting the inner query into the desired *columns*:

```
SELECT subquery1.a, subquery1.b, subquery1.c, 
    myfunction_result[1], myfunction_result[2] 
FROM ( SELECT table1.a, table1.b, table1.c,
              MyFunction(table1.a, table1.b, table1.c) as myfunction_result
       FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 using(b) 
       WHERE ... GROUP BY table1.a, table1.b, table1.c
) AS subquery1;
```

The inner and outer selects will properly correlate the `table1` references.

Comment: That's one of the usual "local variable" tricks and it should work as long as the number of elements in the array is fixed.

Comment: The only problem (and perhaps I should have mentioned this earlier) is that the function depends on other relations of the same query level.  So I'm selecting "table_id", and passing that same id into the function.

Comment: This produces: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "table1" in the first line: SELECT table1.a ...

Comment: You misunderstand my comment, what happens if the array returned from MyFunction sometimes has 2 entries and sometimes 5? You'd have to repeat the `myfunction_result[]` stuff enough times to account for the maximum possible number of entries in the array. That's all I was saying.

Comment: I guess you actually do have to include the columns in the subquery too.  oh well.

Comment: @mu is too short: If the returned array is variadic, or just generally *long*, then it shouldn't be transposed into columns in the first place.  variadic collections should *stay* as arrays.

Comment: A subselect works, formatted as:

`SELECT ta, tb, tc, result[1], result[2] FROM (SELECT table1.a as ta, table1.b as tb, table1.c as tc, MyFunction(table1.a, table1.b, table1.c) as result FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 using(b) WHERE ... GROUP BY table1.a, table1.b, table1.c) as subquery1;`

NOTE that the selecting of all of my columns need to be in both the inner and outer selects.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. A single array column could have, for example, 
one array with three elements and another with five elements. If
you tried to expand those arrays into individual columns, you'd end
up with two rows in a result set that have different numbers of
columns and that is not allowed.

The closest thing available is [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

> expand an array to a set of rows

but that gives you rows rather the columns you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
select data[1] as id, data[2] as value from (SELECT 
string_to_array(rs,':') as data from unnest(string_to_array('1:234,2:400',',')) as rs) as foo
```

This will result as:

```
id|Value
--------
1 | 234
2 | 400
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're try to return a `TABLE` from a `FUNCTION` I found that subselecting did not work for me ([SingleNegationElimination's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960723/409958) returns a single column when used with `RETURN QUERY` inside of a `FUNCTION`) so I had to use `WITH` instead like this:

```sql
CREATE
OR REPLACE FUNCTION STRING_TO_TABLE(
  IN P_STRING text, 
  IN P_DELIMITER text DEFAULT ' '
) RETURNS TABLE (
    FIRST text, 
    SECOND text
) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$

BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY
    WITH SQ AS (
      SELECT STRING_TO_ARRAY(P_STRING, P_DELIMITER) A
    )
    SELECT 
      A[1] AS FIRST,
      A[2] AS SECOND
    FROM SQ;

END $$;
```

which then allows you to use `SELECT...INTO` with the function like this:

```sql
SELECT
  FIRST,
  SECOND
FROM
  STRING_TO_TABLE('first second')
INTO
  P_FIRST,
  P_SECOND;
```