# Array to columns in PostgreSQL when array length is non static

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I need something similar to `unnest()`, but for unnesting to columns rather than rows.

I have a table which has id column and array column. How can I unnest array to columns? Arrays with same ids always have same array length.

EDIT: I'm seeking for query which would work with any array lenght

```
SELECT ???? FROM table WHERE id=1;

id | array                array1 | array2 | ... | arrayn
---+----------            -------+--------+-----+-------
 1 | {1, 2, ..., 3}    ->   1    |   2    | ... |   3
 1 | {4, 5, ..., 6}         4    |   5    | ... |   6
 2 | {7, 8, ..., 9}
```

Anyone got idea?

Comment: What should happen for id 2?

Comment: select ar[1], ar[2] from (select string_to_array('a b c', ' ') ar) as sq;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL convert array returned from function to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960247/postgresql-convert-array-returned-from-function-to-columns)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention that I want query to work with any array length

Comment: That's not possible. The number of columns of a query must be known **before** the query is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this be the logic?

```
select array[1] as array1, array[2] as array2
from t
where id = 1;
```

A SQL query returns a *fixed set of columns*.  You cannot have a regular query that sometimes returns two columns and sometimes returns one or three.  In fact, that is one reason to use arrays -- it gives you the flexibility to have variable numbers of values.

Comment: It works, but I'm seeking for query which works with any array length

Comment: @Simonas have you found the solution?

Comment: @Sergei, no, I haven’t. Instead I first query for `array_upper` and generate final query on application side.